How do I count duplicate rows in a table without using count function
Given the below,
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT employeeId, employeeName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeName ORDER BY employeeId asc) AS rn 
    FROM duplicateEmployee 
) 
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn > 1

I need to count the duplicate records without using count function from the duplicateEmployee table.
Please suggest me to how to modify the above query.

Why do you have to do it without count?

Total number of duplicate records, or duplicates for each name?

All - Looks like a homework question and doesn't deserve castigation.

select sum(rn) from cte ?

@P.Salmon If this is really homework, it's quite a shame. Next homework: Write a query, but don't use SELECT or FROM.

You should use COUNT() for this. Not allowing it is silly and makes this slower and more-complicated. But if you really want to:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT employeeId, employeeName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeName ORDER BY employeeId asc) AS rn 
    FROM duplicateEmployee 
) 
SELECT employeeName, MAX(rn) As DuplicateCount
FROM cte
GROUP BY employeeName


I could have been misunderstanding, but I thought they wanted the total number of duplicates, not by name. I asked for clarification above.

The duplicate count should be max-1 right?

Hello If you want to count the dups from your table without using count function but excluding the original entry in MySql you can do like this much shorter using sum(1) which here count every row:
    SELECT employeeName, sum(1) - 1 as dups_cnt
    FROM duplicateEmployee
group by employeeName;

Hope it helps.
